# Difference between Repository Types and PPA

Tags: software-installation, ppa, repository

When I want to install wine I'm given the instructions to add the repository in the following manner.

```
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

To install PlayOnLinux I'm given similar instructions, but I need to add `deb` and `""` quotations around the URL. Why the difference? Does it even matter?

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ bionic main"
```

And why don't PPA require any URL at all? Is it *given* that the URL is https://launchpad.net/?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:peek-developers/stable
```

Comment: The AskUbuntu Q&A format works best when you ask one question at a time. Which of these questions do you want us to answer? What research have you already done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`man add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html):

```
SYNOPSIS
       add-apt-repository [OPTIONS] REPOSITORY

...

REPOSITORY STRING
       REPOSITORY can be either a line that can be added directly to
       sources.list(5), in the form ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> for adding
       Personal  Package  Archives, or a distribution component to
       enable.

       In the first form, REPOSITORY will just be appended to
       /etc/apt/sources.list.
```

For `"deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ bionic main"`, it will be appended verbatim. That includes having the distribution as `bionic`, even if you're not running Ubuntu Bionic 18.04. (*Note that `playonlinux` is also available in the multiverse repo.*)

For `https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`, add-apt-repository will infer the missing parts:

- type (`deb`)
- distribution (`xenial`, `artful`, `bionic`, etc)
- component (`main`)

```
       In  the  second  form,  ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> will be expanded
       to the full deb line of the PPA and added into a new file in the
       /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ directory.  The GPG public key of the
       newly added PPA will also be downloaded and added to apt's
       keyring.
```

This applies to `ppa:peek-developers/stable`. Yes the host is assumed to be Launchpad.

```
       In the third form, the given distribution component will be
       enabled for all sources.
```

E.g. `universe` or `multiverse`

Details about the sources.list format are from [`man sources.list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/sources.list.5.html).